Publishing extension work for a previous research (in Chemical physics)
I did a project a while back, publishing molecular properties in lengthy tables (paper A). A few years down the line, others used the data in new constructive ways, to obtain insights which were unknown to me.
In some of those works, they extrapolated data to get numbers outside the physical range included in my work. Their extrapolation was excellent though, and they drew correct interpretations.
Recently, I performed a newer analysis for a broader range of physical parameters and this new data is even more extensive. However, no change is observed with the numbers published in my previous work (paper A). I am now able to provide a new set of numbers, although in a different physical space, which is about 20% of my previous dataset in terms of size.
How should I go on to communicate/publish this work? On the one hand, the work is not new (in theory) and only extends the physical parameters and provides tables of numbers. On the other hand, the new dataset is of use to scientists (proved by the recent work in this direction). Another option I am considering is to put in on the institutional website in a compiled pdf (while referring to my earlier work).

My suggestion (as a condensed matter physicist, not a chemical physicist) would be that you start by writing this up as a paper covering the new parameters/tables and providing concrete support for the conclusions of the works that extrapolated the data in your original paper. You say the new dataset is relevant to others. As a consequence, making it available in the primary literature and findable in citation databases is helpful. (A PDF on your website covering both the old and new parameter ranges could also be helpful to some, but is unlikely to have the same discoverability or permanence.) Note that it is certainly OK to sometimes publish new results even if there is no interesting methodological development. We can be blind to how difficult others find applying methods we are very familiar with - after all, if it was that easy, the other group might have done the calculation themselves instead of extrapolating your data.
However, such a paper, even one extending into a clearly relevant parameter range, might be more suitable for journal in a lower tier or different focus than wherever your original paper was published. Nothing wrong with that, of course, but you can also consider extending your new work in various ways: Could you expand the new parameter range further, perhaps by tweaking the method? Are there specific systems your new data can be applied to, or new insights that can be gained in this new physical space? If so, it can be appropriate to write a paper focusing on that new direction, and to add the new tables in a section or appendix.

And, if you get rejected, you can publish privately, as you suggest.

There are numerous options for these types of publications. None are high end, but that is OK. Something like Elsevier's Chemical Physics may be a suitable venue, as long as you can provide a good rationale as to why this parameter space is worthy of being revisited or extended.

There is more interest these days in making datasets available electronically as well. I would think one of the chemical thermodynamics journals would be happy to host an expanded dataset, particularly if the original is being used and cited. Adding more molecules and broader ranges of applicability (and a discussion of how you are doing it) would seem of interest to some journal. Which one is outside my area...

@JonCuster That's true, and there are a couple of options out there. The other thing I would suggest is a general open access journal like RSC Advances or ACS Omega, where the criteria is less about novelty but rather if the work is done well. Being open access they will be broadly available, and being ACS and RSC society journals makes them generally better thought of than some other options. There is a cost but it is not too high and can be completely eliminated based on geographical region/exemptions.
